# Spring boot custom response header blocked by CORS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I have Spring Boot application that provides GET REST API endpoint to a list of objects. The list has a default pagination and provides custom 'Link' HTTP header with info about the next and previous pages based on the current page in the navigation for the client to utilize.

Example of Link HTTP header

```
link: <http://localhost:8080/api/v1/articles?page=1&size=1>; rel="next", <http://localhost:8080/api/v1/articles?page=4&size=1>; rel="last"'
```

When the client and web server utilizes the same origin then the header is included. However, I am unable to include the link header in the response header when the client has different origin. The application has CORS configuration, but I couldn't find anything to make it include my custom header. Only default response headers are included.

Any idea how include custom HTTP headers in the CORS response?

```java
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public SpringDataUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService() {
        return new SpringDataUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin").authenticated().and().formLogin();
    }
 }
```

-- EDIT 1 --

[Response headers when the client is of the same origin as web server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9GuB.png)

[Response headers when the client is on the other port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv9xD.png)

Comment: I added in -- EDIT 1 -- screenshots with response headers when the client is on the same port (same origin) and on different port.

Comment: Look into the debug logs of Spring Security's `DefaultCorsProcessor`. If it is a CORS problem, you should read it there.

Comment: Did you get 200 for both requests? Or did you get 401?

Comment: Both requests have 200 status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. The custom headers must be exposed in CorsConfigurationSource bean. 
Adding this line of code, allowed cross orgin requests to get the custom header 'Link' in response.

```
configuration.addExposedHeader("Link");
```